# Login to a website using Excel - VBA

Tags: excel, authentication, vba

Is there any way to code a program in Excel VBA that can log in to multiple websites? I know some websites need very specific authentication (Twitter, Gmail, etc.), but would it be possible to bypass these and log in to them using the exact same code (only changing the website name, username, and password)?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.

With VBA you can do nearly everything you expect from a more standart procedural language. And there for, yes, you can also make HTTP/HTTPS requests.

But you would need a VBA programmer who also understands HTTP.

See: 
http://www.sourcecodester.com/visual-basic/5882/how-create-program-login-twitter-visual-basic.html

http://itbloggertips.com/2013/07/how-to-auto-login-to-website-gmail-yahoo-using-vbs-vb-script/

This is VB - similar (but not the same as) VBA.